# Gulp watch keeps running after I save the file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I installed gulp to minify my JS file. When I run `gulp watch` the watcher is waiting for the file to change, so that's good.
However, when I modify the file and save it, the watch task is not fired only once, but it keeps getting fired, and it's not stopping. I have to manually stop the task by hitting `ctrl + c`.

This is my `gulpfile.js` file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var minify = require('gulp-minify');

gulp.task('min-js', function() {
    return gulp.src('lib/app.js')
        .pipe(minify({
            ext: {
                min: '.min.js'
            },
            ignoreFiles: ['-min.js']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'))
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  gulp.watch('lib/app.js', gulp.parallel('min-js'));
  // Other watchers
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('min-js', 'watch'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gulp-minify` outputs the source files in addition to the minified files.

See the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify).

Since the output is being piped into the same directory as the input, `lib`, the watcher sees that the input file was overwritten, and triggers again. This causes an infinite loop of watcher triggering minification.

Solutions:

1. Change the output directory to be different from the input directory.
2. Use the `noSource` option on `gulp-minify` to prevent the output of source files.

Comment: You rock that worked great. Also added the noSource and that works also great. It does not create an extra `app.js` file anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var minify = require('gulp-minify');
gulp.task('Minify-JS', function () {
        return gulp.src(['./wwwroot/js/site.js'])
            .pipe(minify({
                ext: {
                    min: '.min.js'
                },
                noSource: true
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/vendors/js'))
            .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    
    });
```